# Why is Error boundary in React JS not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I have a component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Buggy extends Component {
    state = {greeting : 'Welcome'};

    componentDidMount() {
        throw new Error('An error has occured');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h2>{this.state.greeting}</h2>
        );
    }
}

export default Buggy;
```

And a typical `ErrorBoundary` class

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
    state = {error: null, errorInfo: null};

    componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
        this.setState({
            error: error,
            errorInfo: errorInfo
        })
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.errorInfo) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h2>Oops! Something went wrong.</h2>
                </div>
            );
        }
        return this.props.children;
    }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

In `App.js`

```
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <Buggy />
  </ErrorBoundary>
</Fragment>
```

**Yet errors are not handled.**

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: i think component errors outside of `render()` aren't caught, as in the react source the code that applies here is roughly `try{ render() } catch(e) { ... }` I have also noticed this as well, so we use a work around in our render methods to throw all errors from render in a round about way. we literally have a component like `<ThrowError error={this.state.error} />` and all its render method does is `throw this.props.error`

Answer (score 2):

componentDidCatch() is used to log error information not to render fallback UI, use getDerivedStateFromError() for that purpose.

```
  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    logErrorToMyService(error, info);
  }
```

[Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)

Comment: It does actually handle fallback.